# Wrong result using xtile with weighted value in R

Tags: r, weighted

I want to use xtile put the lowest 20% of observations (taking weighting into account) in bin 1, the second 20% of observations in bin 2, and so on, and there are 5 groups in total. The quintil need to be calculated within different years.
The documentiation of xtile function is here: [https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/statar/versions/0.7.3/topics/xtile\](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/statar/versions/0.7.3/topics/xtile%5C)
There is an argument called wt: A variable specifying weight in case the option n_quantiles is specified.
However, the result is not according to the order of the weighted value. Code is stated below:

```
year <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001)
value <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 6, 8, 9, 10, 8)
w <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5)
wt_val <- value * w
check <- as.data.frame(cbind(year, value, w, wt_val))
check_xtile <- check %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(quintil = xtile(value, n=5, wt = w)) %>% ungroup()
```

Result:

```
year value w  wt_val quintil
----------------------------
2000 1     1  1      1
2000 3     2  6      3
2000 5     1  5      5
2000 2     3  6      1
2001 6     6  36     1
2001 8     6  48     1
2001 9     7  63     4
2001 10    7  70     4
2001 8     5  40     1
2003 7     2  14     1
2003 7     2  14     1
```

I think it should be something like:

```
year value w  wt_val quintil
----------------------------
2000 1     1  1      1
2000 3     2  6      5
2000 5     1  5      5
2000 2     3  6      1
2001 6     6  36     1
2001 8     6  48     3
2001 9     7  63     4
2001 10    7  70     5
2001 8     5  40     1
...
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You haven't really explained what the problem is, other than the output is not what you expected. We don't know what you expected because you haven't told us that.

Comment: I just revised the question, hope it's more clear now. Would you mind to take a look at the question again?